# Using multiple v-date-pickers on a single page

Tags: vuetify.js

All:

I'm trying to add multiple Vuetify date pickers to a single page. I'm using it within a v-menu so that when a date is selected it is shown in a text field.

The issue I'm having is: when I select a date for the first date field everything works as expected but when I click to select the second date it is populating the first date field again. I have the following:

```
<div v-for='foo in foos' :key='foo.id'>
    <v-menu
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        v-model="menu"
        :nudge-right="40"
        lazy
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        full-width
        min-width="290px" >
        <v-text-field        
            slot="activator"
            v-model="foo.date"
            label="Date"
            prepend-icon="event"
            readonly>
        </v-text-field>
        <v-date-picker v-model="foo.date" @input="menu = false">.    
        </v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to be respecting that `foo` is different in each iteration of the loop so it is only updating the first instance of `foo.date` instead of the current `foo.date`.

Any advice on how to get this working would be great.

Comment: Thanks @thanksd. I have the key set. I'll update my question to clarify that.

Comment: How is the `menu` property defined? It looks like you're binding every menu's visibility to one variable, which I don't think makes sense unless you're trying to display all of the menus at once for some reason. Here's a working fiddle without the references to `menu`: https://jsfiddle.net/1rjeomz9/

Comment: Hi @thanksd. That worked. I appreciate the help. If you make it a proper answer I'll select it as the correct response.

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @Billy Monk is good but not enough as it restricts you to use v-model for stuff like closing date-picker when a date is selected. You can try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div v-for='foo in foos' :key='foo.id'>
  <v-menu
      v-model="menu[foos.indexOf(foo)]"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      :nudge-right="40"
      lazy
      transition="scale-transition"
      offset-y
      full-width
      max-width="290px"
      min-width="290px"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-text-field
          v-model="foo.date"
          label="Date"
          hint="MM/DD/YYYY format"
          persistent-hint
          prepend-icon="event"
          v-on="on"
        ></v-text-field>
      </template>
      <v-date-picker v-model="foo.date" no-title @input="menu[foos.indexOf(foo)] = false"></v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
data() {
return {
menu: [],
  foos: [
    { id: 1, date: new Date() },
    { id: 2, date: new Date() },
  ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

With @thanksd's help I was able to figure out what the issue was.

The issue is that I was using the menu property for all of my date pickers which meant whenever I clicked on a date input all of the menus were opening. I didn't recognize this, though, because of a CSS issue where only the first date picker was visible on the screen when I clicked a date input.

With only one date picker showing I was using only the visible date picker which was bound to the first input. If I had seen the multiple date pickers I would have noticed that if I used one of the other date pickers a different date input would have been modified.

So thanks, @thanksd!

Comment: This is a good solution. But how do you close the datepicker when a date is selected. When v-model="menu" was passed, we could do @input = "menu =false" inside v-datepicker. How should we accomplish the same here ?